# AIS and RTL-SDR Dongles

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, gnuradio

I am looking for an Windows-based [AIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Identification_System) Decoder for RTL Dongles. Currently, there is a solution available using [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/) and [SDR#](http://sdrsharp.com/) but it is complicated to set up and keep running.

[ADSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance-broadcast) has a dedicated solution called RTL1090 that connects directly to the [RTL-Sdr](http://rtlsdr.org/) stick and decodes the [ADSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance-broadcast) messages in one application.

Does anyone know of a project like this for [AIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Identification_System) Ship Tracking?

Comment: https://github.com/dgiardini/rtl-ais is a windows option that works.

Answer (score 9):

You could check out [ShipPlotter](http://www.coaa.co.uk/shipplotter.htm) which appears to be a windows-based AIS receiver.  It mentions in the webpage that it accepts audio through your sound card.  In the case of RTL-SDR, you'll want to use something like "Virtual Audio Cable" or "[VB-Audio Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/)" to route the audio from sdrsharp to ShipPlotter.

Comment: Thanks, am aware of this, I want to avoid having to use the Audio Cable and Plotter software, just have a standalone decoded that outputs decoded data. I am looking to see if anyone knows of a project started.

Comment: Up-voted as this *is* a valid answer, just not the one the OP was hoping for. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [AISMon](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/aismon/info); I've never used it, but it looks like it fits the bill. Here's a thorough tutorial: http://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-tutorial-cheap-ais-ship-tracking/

Comment: I was hoping to find someone working on a project that combines the audio and decoding so SDR# is not required. ADSB has a package called rtl1090 that does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Three years later:

> Currently, there is a solution available using GNU Radio … but it is complicated to set up and keep running.

Well, you're referring to Nick Foster's [`gr-ais`](https://github.com/bistromath/gr-ais), which is a GNU Radio out-of-tree module, and actually, not that hard to set up.

In fact, it's included in current versions of the [GNU Radio Live DVD](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GNURadioLiveDVD), and you should be able to just boot that, and run `ais_rx`; haven't tried that out lately, because I've installed it directly on my normal system; I've got GNU Radio installed, so the dependencies are already there:

```
git clone https://github.com/bistromath/gr-ais
cd gr-ais
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```